# Printing from PHP with correct line breaks

Tags: php, printing, line-breaks

My code works, but I'm having trouble with line breaks...

I have data saved to a variable as such within a `foreach` loop:

```
$printerdata .=  " " . $product_name . "\n";
$printerdata .=  " $". $price . ".00 \n";
$printerdata .=  " " . $displayoptions . "\n";
$printerdata .=  "\n";
```

Then I post that data and use sockets to print to the printer from my php code. Like I said before, my code works great, but the problem lies with line breaks. When printed from one browser the data is displayed correctly with `"\n"` from the code above, however, when printed from the browser I'm being forced to use called Fresco, I get `whitespace` between the data rather than line breaks.

I've tried `"\r\n"` and that still does not produce any line breaks. I've also tried `<br>` but 
 is literally printed out. Does anyone have any ideas on other ways to produce line breaks within my code? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I haven't tried that. I will try that now. Thank you @segarci

Comment: I don't know if it can help you. Test it and tell us

Comment: I sure will. Thanks for the input. I'll try the few options I received from you all and let you know.

Comment: What is Fresco exactly? The printer model? Also, maybe you just need to set the correct header (header('Content-Type: text/plain')

Comment: ANT Fresco is a discontinued web browser from the 1990's

Answer (score 0):

The php function `nl2br` could help you. This function inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string. You can look it up here:
[nl2br Manual](https://www.php.net/nl2br)

Answer (score 0):

The correct tag is

```
 </br> not <br>
```

But I think in fresco there is also a tag

```
 <af>
```